# How to get cookie in php?

Tags: php, cookies

I want to get cookie to check if my cookie exist or not. But I am not able to do that.

Here the set cookie in my add_cart.php

```
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false); 
//$cart_id is 179, I want to retrieve this cart id
```

Here is what am I doing:

```
// Checking Cookie Exist  in my init.php file 
if (isset($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE])) {
$cart_id = sanitize($_COOKIE[CART_COOKIE]); 
echo "\r\n Cart Id :" . $cart_id;  // Here the value showing 0 instead of 179
}
```

Here is my config.php file

```
 <?php
 define('BASEURL', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/projectdtech/');       
 define('CART_COOKIE','PhsQ547MJjsmcSJ');  
 define('CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE',time() + (86400 *30));  
 ?>
```

I want also check the value of $cart_id in my add_cart.php after reload the page, but after reload it forget the value of $cart_id = 179; It must remember the value of setcoookie($cart_id value). I want to retrieve the value of $cart_id from cookie.

```
if($cart_id != ''){

}
```

This is I want to do but have no idea why my code not working.
Your suggestions would be welcome.
Thank You.

Comment: Ask grand ma, she always gave me cookies....  Make sure you `$domain` is right, cookies are domain specific.  Even subdomains can cause issues such as `www.` vs no subdomain.

Comment: @Devon I am Sorry. I am not using cakephp and codeigniter. I just fill 5 tags for submitting my question. I will not mention again.

Comment: No problem, just make sure you only tag relevant ones in the future, you don't need to fill all 5.

Comment: As suggested above, verify `$domain` and you can also use your browser's developer console to see if a cookie has been set.  Cookies are set on the client side.

Comment: The cookie has been set in the console add_cart.php, network->preserve log -> cookie tab

Comment: You should really be using sessions if you can